# I am getting error in selenuim. I have latest verion of Chrome: 87.0.4280.66. Selenuim Chrome Version: 87

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here's My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
try:
    driver.get('google.com')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```

And My Console :

```
*DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49907/devtools/browser/d1080af1-5c49-4f88-8e6c-976e3440a13c
Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)*
```

Please Help Me get out of this, Plz

Comment: Which line does the error come from?

Comment: At this line error came: `driver.get(".google.com")` I should have changed this into this: `driver.get("https://www.google.com")` I didn't add **https**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the page with using the URL scheme, `https://`

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```